# Pandas create csv with row wise instead columnar

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the below code

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(hh, orient="index")
df.to_csv('reports.csv')
```

Where dict hh is

```
{'domain': 'abcd.com', 'hostname': 'test111', 'ip address': 'xxx.xx.xx.xx', 'status': 'Deployed', 'managed by': 'Sec Team'}
```

instead it come like below

```
domain,hostname,ip address, status, managed by
"abcd.com","test111","xxx.xx.xx.xx","Deployed", "Sec Team"
```

It is comming like below

```
domain, "abcd.com"
hostname,"test111"
ip address, "xxx.xx.xx.xx"
status,"Deployed"
managed by,"Sec Team"
```

How can I make it

```
domain,hostname,ip address, status, managed by
"abcd.com","test111","xxx.xx.xx.xx","Deployed", "Sec Team"
```

Comment: `df.T.to_csv('reports.csv', index=False)`?

Comment: Use `df = pd.DataFrame([hh])` to read. Currently your dataframe is making rows per key-value pairs, that's why to_csv results in 1 key per row.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the option of "orient"?
Like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(hh)
df.to_csv('reports.csv')
```